# Google Cloud Dataflow write to BigQuery (Error 401 : Login Required)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud

I'm trying to write some data to a BigQuery table from my Dataflow Pipeline, but the writes are failing with the following error message in stackdriver :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

I've already tried authenticating my `gcloud` CLI tool by using `gcloud auth application-default login` and `gcloud auth login` prior to running the Dataflow Pipeline from my local machine.

The API for BigQuery is also enabled in my Google Cloud console, **and this entire setup worked just fine few days ago.**

What I think is happening here is that my Dataflow Pipeline doesn't have enough privileges to write to my BQ Table, but I can't find a way to fix this in the docs.

Would appreciate any leads on this.

Comment: Are you running the pipeline on Dataflow, or on your local machine using the DirectRunner?

Comment: Are you remembering to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` before kicking off your pipeline/code? https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable

Comment: @MrtN I'm running it on Dataflow

Comment: @GrahamPolley Yep, done that as my dataflow is already running perfectly fine, which wouldn't have been possible if the credentials were not in place

Comment: Can you share your code please..

Answer (score 0):

The Dataflow runners use a special service account to access resources like BigQuery. You have to give the following service account access to BigQuery:

```
<project-number>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

It is called the [Controller Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions#controller-service-account). In the Dataflow documentation you can also find specific information about [Accessing BigQuery Datasets](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions#accessing-bigquery-datasets-across-google-cloud-platform-projects).

This does not explain why it worked before or why you get a 401 in stead of a 403, but I hope this helps you run your Datafow job.

Comment: This service account is already present 
https://i.imgur.com/MeO7nIq.png

Comment: Great that the service account is present! Does it also have the role `roles/bigquery.dataEditor` assigned so that it is able to read/write data and create tables? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles